# jquery ajax issues with ajaxComplete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to figure the best way to have the response of every ajax call made with jQuery passed through a callback so I can examine for certain states in the return.  For instance, in the case of a users session expiring, my app will return something like:

```
{loggedIn: false}
```

I would assume I could use ajaxComplete but my other callbacks appear to fire first, which is leading to js errors.  What I need to do is:

- run ajax call
- get response, BEFORE any other callbacks fire, pass the result to some global function so I can look for things like {loggedIn: false}
- run other callbacks if everything passes the my global vetting function.

My ajaxComplete code looks like:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, res, settings) {
    var response = eval('(' + res.responseText + ')');

    if (response.hasOwnProperty('logged_in') && ! response.loggedIn) {
        //redirect to log in form or something
    }
});
```

Any ideas why my other callbacks would fire first?

Other Notes:  The following function is called as a result of a backbone.js route, which eventually fires an ajax call to get some images for a specified tag.  this._getImagesForTag simply returns the result of $.ajax(...).

```
function getImagesForTags (tag) {
    var me = this;

    this._getImagesForTag(tag).then(function (r) {
        //reset the collection so we can re-render the canvas
        store.images().reset(r);
    }, function (r) {
        //no images were found so a 404 was sent from the server
        store.images().reset();
    }).complete(function (r) {
        //trigger a tag-changed event
        me.globalEvents.trigger('tag:changed', tag);
    });
};

_getImagesForTag: function (tag) {
    //get imges for some tag from the api
    return $.gallery('api/images/tags/' + tag, {type: 'get'});
},
```

and finally:

```
$.extend({
    gallery: function (url, data) {
        //send a request to an arbitrary url with some data. Expects to
        //get json returned.
        return $.ajax(State.url + url, $.extend({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post'
        }, data));
    }
});
```

Hmm...I wonder if my .complete() from getImagesForTags is overriding my ajaxComplete?

Comment: please, consider that eval is evil ;) (you can see that in several articles). That is very rare that eval is necessary. You may be interested in using JSON (and jQuery implements it).

Comment: For your problem, is this handler declared before the other handlers? If not, can you try that ?

Comment: re: eval - Fair enough, and I will consider it for my production code.  I have it hear as an example of how I want to get at res when it's not an object (in the case of ajaxComplete it's just a string of the text).  Will look into other ways, if I can get the ajaxComplete to fire first :)

Comment: This callback is added first.  My other callbacks are fired as a result of a backbone.js route, which happen after the binding of ajaxComplete.

Comment: Can you edit your post so we can see how the other callbacks look like, please ?

Comment: Edited.  Thanks for your interest fflorent.